# How to get the index of the max value of each list in the array?

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy, numpy-ndarray

So I have this array,

**a = np.array([[5,10,1,3], [1,5,1,5], [0,3,1,8]])**

and I wish to show the index of the max value of each.
the output will be shown like this

**'1,1,3'**

as 5 is the max value of the 1st element and it's index is 1,
as 5 is the max value of the 1st element and it's index is 1, and
as 8 is the max value of the 1st element and it's index is 3.

I have tried some function, like max and do the looping, and argmax, but I couldn't find the right answer. I am really new to python.

please help me with the function that can return the output regardless the length of the array.
Thank you..

Comment: np.argmax(a, axis=1)? see [NumPy doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html)

Comment: thank you so much.. I've tried this. np.argmax(a, axis=1), and this is the result "array([1,1,3])", can you help me again? how can I return the number only..

Comment: What do you want to do by them? you can loop on them or used them as you want by indexing in NumPy or …. For help you must explain what you want to do with them and what did you try.

Comment: Sorry..

def display_max(a):
  x= np.argmax(a, axis=1)
  y= list(x.flatten())
  return y

, I've tried this.. and the output is
[1,1,3]

, the output that I want is this
1,1,3

, Thank you for helping me..

Comment: You can't do this, they must be inside lists or arrays. What do you want to do by 1,1,3? where these values will be used again as input?? write next functions or … where these values will be used to help.

Comment: I got the challenge from my tutor..  and in the question, he define the exact output..

Answer (score 0):

Your idea works fine for me:

```
a.argmax(axis=1)
```

yields:

```
Out[]: array([1, 1, 3])
```

same for `np.argmax(a,axis=1)`